# Does Magento coupons support rest value?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magento-1.7

Customers in our store can buy gift certificates. We create them in the backend and then handwrite a gift card with that coupon code. If a customer now buys a 50€ coupon and the giftet person only selects stuff for 30€ in the online store, what happens with the rest value? In Germany there is a law that this rest value must either be available with that coupon or we have to pay it out. Of course, we prefer the first solution, but it this possible within the magento coupon stuff?

We use Magento CE 1.7.0.2 with NO extension for the coupons. Just the [regular method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them).

I have postet this also on [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225654/does-magento-coupons-support-rest-value) before I found this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Magento CE does not support this. (EE does).
If the discount value is over the cart total then the grand total is set to 0 and the discount rule is marked as used. If you have a limit to 1 use then it cannot pe used again. I suggest using an extension for this.
I've used this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-giftcert.html a log time ago (when it was free) but you can find many with a simple search. I think it's worth to spend 100 - 200 $ on an extension instead of developing it.

Comment: Unirgy is the extension I get recommended too.

Comment: Reading the comments of the unirgy extension, I doubt that especially that one is a good choice (updates, one-step-checkout a.s.o.). Can you recommend another one that you already used maybe?

Comment: Sorry. I've used only the one from unirgy and one that I made myself. But the one I made myself is only compatible with the Magento 1.1 (really old version) and was custom made for the client requirements. And I can say that the effort of making one is not worth it. Look on Magento Connect for such extensions and read the reviews. You will figure out which one fits best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Gift Card extension found on http://www.shopmages.com/gift-card-by-magestore.html
that we just added to the newly dev store vitalbox

It support gift card repository - so customer is able to use gift cards during checkout. if the gift card is not fully used - remaining amount can be used on other transaction.

The only one problem I see is that I cannot attach gifts via admin to the customer pocket, but if I send it by email customer is able to attach them by himself. Also I found that gift cards value can be exchanged as store credit (no expiration date).

I hope it helped a bit.